# Flex DownloadProgressBar preloader override

Tags: apache-flex

I'm watching this video, which is pretty good http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play?id=108 It shows how to inherit from DownloadProgressBar to create a customer preloader for your flex app. The DownloadProgressBar class has an overridable getter for the property 'preloader.' Isn't this poor design? What does a property called preloader have anything to do with a class for a DownloadProgressBar?

Answer (score 1):

The `preloader` property is write-only, so there is no overridable getter. As for it's purpose, from the [documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/preloaders/DownloadProgressBar.html):

> The Preloader class passes in a reference to itself to the display class so that it can listen for events from the preloader